# how to access another class's listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

so i have class 1. class 1's XML file has a list view. i also have class 2. i would like for class 2 to uses class 1's listview.

```
your_array_list.add("foo");
    your_array_list.add("bar");

    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
    // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
    // array as a third parameter.
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            your_array_list );

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

this is the code to add items to the listview but i cant get class 2 to use this code on class 1's listview.

Comment: You are combining both of the arraylist so the first thing would be that both of the arraylist should be of the same type. If that is the situation then i have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in a similar situation where I wanted to access an integer from multiple activities. What I did was this:

1. Create a **new** java class

[image]

2. Make an array list in that java class. **Make sure it is static so that you can use it from other classes/activities**

   3.Now, to access it in another class, do the following:

   ClassName.myArrayList.add("Doing from another class!");

In the other class, it can just be one arrayList, and it doesn't have to be much. It can only have one purpose, and to house your global variable:

```
 public class ClassName{
ArrayList <String> myArrayList = new ArrayList <String>();
}
```

Fun Fact:

**You are already accessing tons of variables from other classes. For example, that `R.id.*` thing we always use...We access it from the `R` class**